# Index of matching bracket character within a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, brackets

I'm more curious than in dire need. Would it be possible to pass a lambda function two arguments `s`, and `i`. Where `s` is the string in question and `i` is the index of the first bracket; and have it return the index of the complimentary bracket?

I should note that it only needs to work for the brackets `()`, and not `{}` or `[]`.

**For example**

```
>>> f( '(() foo ) bar' , 0)
8
```

*`f` is defined by a lambda function*

Edit: I'm aware that numerous methods exist for finding the matching bracket. I, however, am curious if it can be simplified into a lambda expression.

Comment: It can. But it won't be pretty.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, I'd assume it wouldn't be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm far too lazy to worry about corner cases, but using `itertools.accumulate` it's relatively straightforward:

```
f = lambda s,i: next((i for i,x in enumerate(accumulate
    ({'(': 1, ')': -1}.get(c,0) for c in s[i:]), i) if not x), None)

In [31]: s = '(() foo ) bar'

In [32]: f(s, 0)
Out[32]: 8

In [33]: f(s, 1)
Out[33]: 2

In [34]: f(s, 2)
```

This works by tracking the height of the string, counting ( as +1 and ) as -1:

```
In [36]: list(accumulate({'(': 1, ')': -1}.get(c,0) for c in s))
Out[36]: [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```